# How to hide bottom side Css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sass

Here is what I have tried:

```
 &__ellipse {
        width: 297px;
        height: 297px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        background: $orange;
        position: relative;

        img {
          position: absolute;
          bottom: 0;
          right: 20px;
        }
      }
```

How can I hide only the bottom side? Something like this `overflow-bottom: hide`, or `clip path`
[image]

Comment: Have you tried `border-radius: 100%`  ??

Comment: share the image file

Comment: @TemaniAfif https://ibb.co/P6zHcHP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do it like below using mask and gradient:

```css
.box {
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0 35px 32px 0; /* to rectify the image position */
  max-width: 200px;
  /* the orange circle with gradient */
  background: radial-gradient(circle closest-side, orange 85%, transparent 86%);
  -webkit-mask: 
    /* show only the orange circle (same as background  */
    radial-gradient(circle closest-side, orange 85%, transparent 86%),
    /* and also show 70% from the top */ 
    linear-gradient(#fff, #fff) top/100% 70% no-repeat; 
}

.box img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Kjvd.png">
</div>
```

Another version using multiple backoground. Easier to manage and responsive

```css
.box {
  display:inline-block;
  --grad:radial-gradient(circle closest-side at 50% 58%, orange 97%, transparent 98%);
  background: 
    url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Kjvd.png) 0 50%/contain no-repeat, var(--grad);
  -webkit-mask: var(--grad), linear-gradient(#fff, #fff) top/100% 70% no-repeat;
}

.box::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  padding-top: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box" style="width:300px"></div>
<div class="box" style="width:200px"></div>
<div class="box" style="width:100px"></div>
```